# How to convert a string with numbers to an array with integer elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this: `'3,6,43,8'`.

I can convert it to an array easily:

```
$newArray = explode( ',', $string );
```

but as I need integer elements in the array, I should convert every array element to an integer:

```
foreach( $newArray as $key => $sNumber ) {
    $newArray[ $key ] = intval( $sNumber );
}
```

Is there a way to directly convert the array elements to integers, instead of strings?

Comment: Php transform the data automatically. (as far as i know)

Comment: @ManishMishra - Ups! Yes, sorry.

Comment: np buddy! just make sure, you scout SO and google properly :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$inty = array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php

     $integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, why are all your answers "Try this: XXX -- Thanks"?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$val = '3,6,43,8';
$integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $val));
var_dump($integerIDs);
```

with var_dump you can check it type.